# Is there a Yelp equivalent in Malaysia?

Tags: online-resources, malaysia, restaurants, mobile-apps

In Malaysia, Yelp has already advanced and the quantity of the data looks decent enough.

However I wonder there is any better alternative (e.g. in quantity, more search filter, etc) service like Yelp offered by local companies.

I don't mind if it is only in Malay. Is there any such app or is Yelp the only decent service in this field?

Answer (score 2):

According to [SimilarWeb](https://www.similarweb.com/top-websites/malaysia/category/food-and-drink/restaurants-and-delivery), the most popular local reviews sites are [OpenRice](https://my.openrice.com/) and [Zomato](https://www.zomato.com/malaysia).

Answer (score 0):

Foursquare is your friend https://foursquare.com/ the have iOS and Andriod apps too.